# Worker in JavaScript terminate if taking more than a specified time

Tags: javascript, timeout, web-worker

I want to run a function using a Web Worker in JavaScript, but I want to terminate the worker if the worker does not return any result within 2 minutes. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: How can it be done? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes shure, simply *terminate* :

```
var worker=new Worker("src.js");
worker.postMessage("init");//give some task

setTimeout(function(){
  worker.terminate()
},2*60*1000);

window.addEventListener("message",somehandler);
```

Comment: Does it work even if I create a new worker in a loop? And for each iteration of loop I check this condition.

Comment: @ShivaniAggarwal theres no condition. but yes it should work